# Select to open a HTML file from local hard drive to save as MHT file then import to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to open a dialogue box to select a HTML file by clicking on a button in Excel.

Once it opens the file, I need to save it as a mht file with the same name, in the same directory it was opened from. Then import the mht file to excel (it keeps it's format that way).

So far I've only come across the code:

```
'.Navigate C://file path'
```

which is no good as the files are always in different locations.

The code I've got so far is:

```
Sub Convert_HTML()

Dim ie As Object
Dim MyFile As String

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With ie

    .Navigate MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("html Files (*.html), *Jackstandwithfoil*.html", 1, "Open Jackstand with foil HTML File")
    .Visible = True


End With

ie.Visible = True

End Sub
```

This gets me the dialogue box to select the HTML file, opens IE (my work's preferred browser).
But I get IE trying to open "http://false/" instead of the selected file.
If I click close/Cancel, the same web address comes up.

I'm trying to automate an Excel form for work so we don't have to open the file, then 'save as' multiple times a day which is needed for proof for clients.

I've searched many forums for the same/similar code needed so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

> .Navigate MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("html Files (*.html), *Jackstandwithfoil*.html", 1, "Open Jackstand with foil HTML File")

**To**

```
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("html Files (*.html), *Jackstandwithfoil*.html", 1, "Open Jackstand with foil HTML File")

.Navigate MyFile
```

This template creates a new workbook in Excel and sets a reference to the first worksheet.

```
Const WorkBookPath = "C:\My Excel Files\Sales.xls"
Const WorkSheetName = "Sales Data"

Dim xlApplication, xlWorkbook, xlWorksheet
Set xlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApplication.Visible = True
Set xlWorkbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open()
Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

xlWorksheet.Range("A1") = 10


xlWorkbook.Save
xlWorkbook.Close
xlApplication.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks! Been trying to get the save as to work ever since. Do you know how? Can only get Excel to save a workbook

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick replies and your help. I meant I'm trying to get IE to save the HTML as mht where the selected HTML file is found.

The only thing I can get to work is saving an excel workbook which isn't what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've not managed to save as a mht. Looking at many forums and being a novice, I couldn't get anything to work and definitely couldn't read/understand enough of it to alter it.

I've simply got it to copy & paste straight from a HTML file selected by the user in to the current workbook (the one I found opened a new workbook every time).

You may need to create a macro to change the layout of the sheet or have one already set up like I do.

```
Sub Import_JST_woFoil()

Dim OST As Workbook
Dim IE As Object    
Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 'user selects file

Set OST = ThisWorkbook 'Doesn't need to be renamed. Rename to your Excel file name but MAKE SURE you rename the OST part above

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
If MyFile = False Then Exit Sub 'Exits if Cancel or Close is clicked

IE.Visible = True 'Opens IE window
IE.Navigate MyFile 'Opens/views web page from file selected

'Wait to load page
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

'Below selects all & copy on webpage
IE.ExecWB 17, 2
IE.ExecWB 12, 2

Sheets("JST without Foil").Select 'Selects separate tab (Rename JST without Foil to whatever your tab is called)
ActiveSheet.Paste Range("A1") 'Pastes from cell A1
IE.Visible = False 'closes IE
Sheets("OutputForm").Select 'Selects original tab (Rename OutputForm to whatever tab you want to see at the end of the macro). Delete this line if you want to stay on the tab you paste the web page on to.


End Sub
```

I can supply links to the thread later (I don't have this to hand).

If you want to search for only a HTML file and no other type, replace

```
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
```

With

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("HTML Files (*.HTML), *<common filename>*.HTML", 1, "Open <common name> File")
```

Hope this helps others!